# mysql not connect with php scripts?

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, wampserver

```
<?php
$cons=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("infogallery") or die('Not Connected to the data base:'.mysql_error()); 
?>
```

I write above code for connection with mysql but when i run this scripts..nothing display on the brouser...what can i do for the connection with mysql....

Comment: Zero upvotes and zero accepts.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing is displayed, then it means it succeeded.  Add more code which queries the database and displays some results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't connect as the root account. Create an account specifically for playing around with.

Once you've done that, modify your code as follows:

```
$cons = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if ($cons === FALSE) {
   die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db(etc.....);
```

You don't check if the connection failed, then try to do a database operation on that potentially failed connection. The `or die(...)` you have will only show the error caused by the `select` attempt, and the error message from the failed connection will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I like to just do

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("infogallery") or die(mysql_error());
echo "So far, so good.";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following:

```php
<?php
try {
    $cons = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
} catch ($e) {
    die('Failed to connect to the database: ' . mysql_error());
}

try {
    mysql_select_db("infogallery", $cons);
} catch ($e) {
    die('Failed to select the database: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```